# Qt generate info.plist file

Tags: qt, plist

I created an application which will change version frequently and I don't want to generate manually a info.plist file at each new version like with [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/OS_X_application_without_menu_bar) solution.

I've tried with this snippet :

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
a.setApplicationVersion(APP_VERSION);
a.setOrganizationName(ORG_NAME);
a.setOrganizationDomain(ORG_NAME);
```

but it doesn't change a thing, even if I delete the app bundle and make a new one...

Comment: You could write a shell script generating your plist and call this script from your .pro file as extra_target

Comment: @SebastianLange But Qt generate a semi-generic plist file, that should be customizable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by running a hand made script :

```
# For the plist version
QMAKE_INFO_PLIST +=  $${TARGET}/data/default.plist
QMAKE_POST_LINK += sed -i -e "s/@VERSION@/$$VERSION/g" "./$${TARGET}.app/Contents/Info.plist";
```

Comment: And for anyone with spaces in their TARGET name who gets stuck on the quotes disappearing, the right way to escape them so they get sent to the shell is \""$${TARGET}\"".

Comment: Here's a more complete example: https://forum.qt.io/topic/6176/qmake-qmake_info_plist-and-typeinfo/2